# Date function in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure to get the weekly result. So, with two input parameters(startDate, endDate) I can get the result which I expected. But the **problem here is, when the week starts from 28/08/2015 and end at 03/09/2015 am getting 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34 as days of the week. But expected result is 28, 29, 30, 31, 01, 02, 03, 04.**

Here is my code for the above details. Help me to overcome this problem

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Get_TimesheetDetails]
    @UserID int, @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @intStartDate int
declare @intEndDate int
declare @strMonth varchar(50)

SELECT @intStartDate =   DATEPART(day,@startDate) 

    Select @intEndDate = DATEPART(day,@endDate)

    select @strMonth =  DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())

declare @temptable table (num int)

declare @columns varchar(max)
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(1000); 
    DECLARE @startnum INT=@intStartDate-1
DECLARE @endnum INT=@intEndDate


;
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass start date and end date values as dates and not as Integers.

Try this...

```
DECLARE @startnum DATE = '20150828'  --<-- Use ANSI date `YYYYMMDD`
DECLARE @endnum   DATE = '20150903'


;WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,num) FROM gen 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,num) <= @endnum
)
SELECT * FROM Gen
```

### Result:

```
   num
2015-08-28
2015-08-29
2015-08-30
2015-08-31
2015-09-01
2015-09-02
2015-09-03
```

Comment: yeah got it. Simple but missed. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass start date and end date instead of integer values. Try this

```
DECLARE @startnum DATE = '08/28/2015'
DECLARE @endnum DATE ='09/03/2015';

DECLARE @startnum DATE = '08/28/2015'
DECLARE @endnum DATE ='09/03/2015';

WITH gen
     AS (SELECT @startnum AS DAT
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(DD, 1, DAT)
         FROM   gen
         WHERE  DAT <= @endnum)
SELECT RIGHT('0' + Cast(Day(DAT) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
FROM   GEN
```

**Note :** Since here the date range is very small i have used recursive cte approach else you can use tally table to generate dates

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using a strongly-typed date but without the recursive CTE loop.

```
WITH 
    t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t64 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) - 1 AS num FROM t4 AS a, t4 AS b, t4 AS c)
SELECT DATEADD(day, num, @StartDate)
FROM t64
WHERE num <= DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate);
```